# Directive with two way value binding and typeahead

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive with an input field with bootstrap typeahead.
Like this:

```
<my-input value="myCar" value-expr="car as car.name for car in cars"></my-input>
```

with an output like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myCar" typeahead="car as car.name for car in cars"/>
```

myCar and cars are values of the parent scope, so i think have to choose *scope: true* in my directive to access the values. I have many my-input directives on my page with different changed values. 
My directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: 'my-input.html',
  compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
      inputEl = tElement.find('input');
      inputEl.attr('typeahead', tAttrs.valueExpr);
      inputEl.attr('ng-model', tAttrs.value);
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.changed= false;
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is: if i choose an car with my typeahead, the myCar value of the directive scope changes but the myCar value of the parent scope doesn't change. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Maybe using Angular-UI-Bootstrap's typahead would help: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @m.e.conroy I'am using Angular-UI-Bootstrap's typahead

Comment: Can I ask what is the value add of this directive, it seems that you're just swapping attribute names and in the process creating isolated scopes.

Comment: Setting `scope: true` creates a new child scope, you've basically unlinked the directive's scope from the parent controller's scope in one direction.  If the value of the parent changed it would be reflected in the directive but if the value in the directive changed it wouldn't work its way up to the parent.

Comment: Yes it looks like but it's only a part of the whole directive. The directive shows the value(myCar) as Text and at onClick the input field with typeahead shows up. Yes exactly this is my problem. I need a two way bind of the myCar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work for you:

```
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        ngModel : '=',
        cars : '='
    },
    template : '<input ng-model="ngModel" typeahead="car as car.name for car in cars">',
    replace : true
};
```

Then your HTML would look like this:

```
<my-input ng-model="myCar" cars="cars"></my-input>
```

This creates a two-way binding between your directive and your parent controller's scope variables, *cars* probably doesn't need to be two-way bound though

**EDIT**

Even simpler solution you could just keep scope out of it altogether like this:

```
return {
    restict : 'E',
    template : '<input type="text" typeahead="car as car.name for car in cars">',
    replace : true
};
```

Then the HTML

```
<my-input ng-model="myCar"></my-input>
```

The *ngModel* attribute will automatically make it into your template as an attribute and retain binding to the parent controller.

**EDIT - with changing expression for typeahead**

```
.directive('myInput', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<input type="text">'
        replace : true,
        link : function($scope,el){
            var model = el.attr('ng-model');
            var ta = el.attr('value-expr');
            return $compile($('input',el).attr('ng-model',model).attr('typeahead',ta))($scope);
        }
    };
 }) // end directive
```

HTML:

```
<my-input ng-model="myCar" value-expr="car as car.name for car in cars"></my-input>
```

**EDIT - Update Parent Scope but maintain directive scope**

```
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    template : '<input type="text" ng-model="value" typeahead="{{valueExpr}} | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item,$model,$label)" class="form-control">',
    scope : {
        value : '=',
        collection : '=',
        valueExpr : '@'
    },
    link : {
        pre :  function(scope,el){
            /*var ta = el.attr('value-expr');
            return $compile($('input',el).attr('ng-model',scope.ngModel).attr('typeahead',ta))(scope);*/
            //$compile($('input',el));
        },
        post : function(scope,el,attrs){
            scope.changed = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/3mgx5f7o/3/

Comment: Yes, this works for my example but i don't want to lose flexibility of the typeahead expression. I want to reuse my directive for other typeaheads like ...="car.brand as car.name for car in cars"

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works partly, the problem now is that we have no directive scope but i think we need them to handle the active flag (for view / edit mode)

Comment: @Christoph Got it working, added a fiddle to show it working with updating the parent scope and maintaining an isolate scope in the directive.